# Pandas: How to print rows containing specified element of list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe that looks like this (sample):

```
column1     column2            column3
  xyz         123         [(ab,cv), (da,ndfds)]
  dsja        32421            [(ab,cv)]
  dgsag       3252        [(dsfsa,sfa), (sd,sfag)]
 ....................
```

I first of all would like to get the most frequently occurring pairs within all lists. 
For example:

```
 (ab,cv)    2
 (da,ndfds) 1
 ..........
```

I would like to be able to call all of the rows which contain the entry (ab,cv) in column3 for example.

The expected output for this would be:

```
 column1     column2            column3
  xyz         123         [(ab,cv), (da,ndfds)]
  dsja        32421            [(ab,cv)]
  .....................
```

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a general comment: Pandas is amazing, but the moment you start having tuples inside lists inside columns, it's probably not the right tool anymore. Pandas is designed for tabular data, what you are dealing with is clearly more structured.

This being said, here is my solution.

First, let's create the `DataFrame` (so that the example is riproducible):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': ['xyz', 'dsja', 'dgsag'],
    'col_2': [123, 32421, 3252],
    'col_3': [
        [('ab','cv'),('da','ndfds')], 
        [('ab','cv')], 
        [('dsfsa','sfa'),('sd','sfag')]]
})
```

which gives

```py
>>> df
    col_1   col_2   col_3
0   xyz     123     [(ab, cv), (da, ndfds)]
1   dsja    32421   [(ab, cv)]
2   dgsag   3252    [(dsfsa, sfa), (sd, sfag)]
```

Now, counting occurrences is easy through `collections.Counter`, and you need to concatenate all those lists first:

```py
from collections import Counter

Counter(t for row in df['col_3'] for t in row)

Counter({('ab', 'cv'): 2,
         ('da', 'ndfds'): 1,
         ('dsfsa', 'sfa'): 1,
         ('sd', 'sfag'): 1})
```

the `Counter` object you obtain has a `most_common` method, which accepts as an argument the number of items you want (e.g. the 3 most common occurrences).

Now, the second point is just logical indexing. You can index through `loc`, and (improved based on other answers below) use a generator to make the comparison:

```py
t = ('ab', 'cv')

df.loc[(t in l for l in df['col_3']), :]

    col_1   col_2   col_3
0   xyz     123     [(ab, cv), (da, ndfds)]
1   dsja    32421   [(ab, cv)]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df[[any(y in l for y in x) for x in df.col3]]
Out[57]: 
  col1                     col3
0    x  [(ab, cv), (da, ndfds)]
1    y               [(ab, cv)]
```

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['x','y','z'],'col3':[[('ab','cv'), ('da','ndfds')],[('ab','cv')],[('dsfsa','sfa'), ('sd','sfag')]]})
l=[('ab','cv'),('da','ndfds')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
df[('ab','cv') in l for l in df.column3]
    column1 column2 column3
0   xyz 123 [(ab,cv),(da,ndfds)]
1   dsja    32421   [(ab,cv)]
```